# How do you brawl on a custom stage?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

My sister and I made a stage on SSBB, and we were wondering, how do we brawl on a custom stage?

Answer (score 8):

At the stage select screen, navigate to the *Melee Stages* page. There should be a *Custom Stages* button in the bottom right corner. Image:

[image]